# I want to be able to delete an object from the api and re render the function without having to manually refresh the page, how can I do that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

```
const Notes = () => {
  const history = useNavigate();

  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://6390acc765ff4183111b53e9.mockapi.io/notes`)
      .then((getData) => {
        setApiData(getData.data);
      });
  }, []);

  const onDelete = (id) => {
    axios
      .delete(`https://6390acc765ff4183111b53e9.mockapi.io/notes/${id}`)
      .then(() => {
        history("/notes");
      });
  };
```

This way I can delete the note that i fetched earlier, but it still appears on the screen until I refresh manually. It doesn't also go to /notes because i am already on /notes

Comment: Couldn't you update your 'apiData' if the delete was successful?
Something like 'setApiData( prev => prev.filter( item => item.id !== id ) )' right before 'history ("/notes")'.
That would only be possible if the items from your 'apiData' list have an 'id' attribute.

Comment: In case you missed it from the [tour] there are 100% completely optional actions one can take after [someone answers] that helps curate content on the site. Cheers and good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either return the updated data in the delete response to update the local state, or you can trigger a refetch of the data after a successful deletion.

Refetch Example:

```
const Notes = () => {
  const history = useNavigate();

  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);

  const fetchNotes = useCallback(async () => {
    const getData = await axios
      .get(`https://6390acc765ff4183111b53e9.mockapi.io/notes`);
    setApiData(getData.data);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchNotes();
  }, [fetchNotes]);

  const onDelete = async (id) => {
    await axios
      .delete(`https://6390acc765ff4183111b53e9.mockapi.io/notes/${id}`);
    fetchNotes();
    history("/notes");
  };

  ...
```

Returned response Example*:

```
const Notes = () => {
  const history = useNavigate();

  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://6390acc765ff4183111b53e9.mockapi.io/notes`)
      .then((getData) => {
        setApiData(getData.data);
      });
  }, []);

  const onDelete = async (id) => {
    const getData = await axios
      .delete(`https://6390acc765ff4183111b53e9.mockapi.io/notes/${id}`);
    setApiData(getData.data);
    history("/notes");
  };

  ...
```

*Note: This requires updating the backend code to return the updated data in the response.

Comment: I tried the refetch example and it worked perfectly, thank you for your help!
There's only one thing i think should be corrected, the prop/state in useEffect should remain blank or it will give an error. I don't really know why but it worked this way. I am new to programming btw and still learning. 

  `useEffect(() => {
    fetchNotes();
  }, []);`

Comment: @Wise.Wolf Yeah, you can do it that way. If you've the react-hooks linting rules added your project it may complain about missing dependencies which is why I tried to show an example where the fetching function is memoized via the `useCallback` hook.

Comment: Ah then you are correct because i forgot to mention that I did as you suggested but without the useCallback, this is why it probably gave an error. Your help is really appreciated!